# Change UIViewcontroller with if statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, xcode-storyboard

I'm have two view controllers that are same the only difference is first show a mapview and other isn't show a mapview.

In this case, i have segmented control where in segment 0 is displaying the View Controller with the mapView but I have some other data that doesn't have information to be displayed in the mapview. I would like to know how I could do this (with an if statement or something similar) since the other UIView does not have segue.

[image: View Controller with mapview]

[image: Infos]

Comment: Can you set the height constraint to 0 when you don't want to show the map view?

Comment: @J.Wang yes but appears a lot of conflict constraints after set this

Comment: Shouldn't be if you set them correctly. What are the conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a bad practice. If your app needs 2 or more screens with similar design, then you should be using one viewcontroller/scene only. This way, if a design change happens, you only need to change once.

2 viewcontrollers with difference of only a map visibility isn't hard to code. You just declare a property bool for that viewcontrollerA like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isMapVisible;
```

Then on viewDidload on viewControllerA, you set the visibility of this map by:

```
if (!_isMapVisible) {
  [_mapView setHidden = YES];
}
```

The caller viewcontroller then implements prepareForSegue and set the _isMapVisible accordingly prior to executing the segue to viewControllerA.

Comment: If i use this my view will appears a blank space ?

Comment: Actually I am not sure what you want. That is just an example how to use single Viewcontroller and display data on them differently based on the caller. in the if statement, you need to write your own method - for example, put all objects related to mapView in another UIView, and then set the height-constraint of this UIView to 0 in this if statement. And that is if you use Constraints at all. If you don't use constraints, then you must position things manually. There are many possibilities, you need to give more info on your code/storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can set mapview height to 0 if you want to hide it. Like:

```
mapView.frame.size.height = 0
```